# ExecuteSQL processor in Nifi returns data in avro format

Tags: oracle, hadoop, bigdata, apache-nifi, avro

Just started working with Apache Nifi. I am trying to fetch data from oracle and place it in HDFS then build an external hive table on top of it. The problem is ExecuteSQL processor returns data in avro format. Is there anyway I can get this data in a readable format?

Comment: please post the code you tried...

Answer (score 2):

apache nifi also has an 'ConvertAvroToJSON' processor.  That might help you get it into a readable format.  We also really need to just knock out the ability for our content viewer to nicely render avro data which would help as well.

Thanks
joe